# How to ignore pointer events for a Snackbar in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How could I disable the behavior of absorbing pointer events by a `SnackBar`.

e.g. when a `SnackBar` is visible, I want to be able to click a button underneath the `SnackBar`.

A `SnackBar` can be showed as follows:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(Snackbar(content: Text('Hello')));
```

The problem is that the `showSnackBar(SnackBar snackBar)` method takes a `SnackBar` type as a parameter, so it is not possible to wrap the `SnackBar` by the `IgnorePointer` widget.

Do you have any solution for this except copy pasting Flutter's `SnackBar` State class and inheriting from the Flutter's `SnackBar`?